FYI - informed LEGO of the existence of bricks.se
I've just sent the following message to Jan Beyer, LEGO community manager, to inform him of the existence of bricks.se, now that it's moved to public beta.
My reasoning if twofold: one, make some publicity for the site, possibly reaching out to fellow experts; and two, make sure everything is OK from a legal point of view. Better knowing about issues sooner than later.

(snipped gossip not related to bricks.se)
There's a new site on LEGO which uses the question and answer format
pioneered by Stack Overflow, a programming Q&A site.
So far, there have been quite a few interesting questions, including
the one with the minifig head, and things look promising.
The site is https://bricks.stackexchange.com/ and is thus focussed on
LEGO questions.
However, I have a feeling that there aren't many experts on board now,
and it would be great if we could attract more.
Could you pass the link around? Via the ambassadors, we should be able
to reach a few more persons.
Of course, having actual LEGO employees provide canonical answers
would be even better, but I understand that's going to be very though
to organise, since they may not always speak freely. Maybe your team
can survey the site and see if there are questions which you feel are
worthy of an official answer from LEGO, and if so interrogate the
right persons internally.
One last thing - could you check that everything is OK from a legal
point of view?
I think the most important things are covered, but if there's anything
which bothers you, it's better that the site admins know it sooner
than later.
Thanks a lot for the answer, and I hope to see you on bricks.stackexchange.com !

Edit: here are some preliminary comments from Jan — note that these don't mean that LEGO approves of anything else; as a matter of fact I think they'll probably want to contact SE owners directly as Jan also asked who was running the site, but it's a start:

Regarding the website - it should not be called LEGO Answers - this imply that the LEGO Group answers but perhaps "Answers regarding LEGO bricks".
Also LEGO needs to be written always in capital letters and should never stand alone so LEGO bricks, LEGO Sets ...


I'd love to have product designers like Jamie Berard answer question on Lego...

Yeah, I wish too, but I know from experience this isn't going to be easy - they have to be careful what they say, etc... so most of the time their communications go through other channels. But we can dream about it :-)

sniff  No more Brick Overflow, but that's all right.

Good call. 
So far they generally show a positive approach to community activity as long as it doesn't go outside policy, and I think we've kept within the rules, so getting them in here to strengthen the community will be incredibly valuable
